# Is there a difference between lambdas declared with and without async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, lambda, async-await

Is there a difference between lambdas `() => DoSomethingAsync()` and `async () => await DoSomethingAsync()` when both are typed as `Func<Task>`? Which one should we prefer and when?

Here is a simple console app

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace asyncDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var demo = new AsyncDemo();
            var task = demo.RunTheDemo();
            task.Wait();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class AsyncDemo
    { 
        public async Task Runner(Func<Task> action)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " Launching the action");
            await action();
        }

        private async Task DoSomethingAsync(string suffix)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " Done something, " + suffix);
        }

        public async Task RunTheDemo()
        {
            await Runner(() => DoSomethingAsync("no await"));
            await Runner(async () => await DoSomethingAsync("with await"));
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
09:31:08 Launching the action
09:31:10 Done something, no await
09:31:10 Launching the action
09:31:12 Done something, with await
```

So in `RunTheDemo`, both calls to `await Runner(someLambda);` appear to do the same thing with the same timing characteristics - both have the correct two-second delay.

Both lines work, so are they exactly equivalent? What is the difference between the  `() => DoSomethingAsync()` and `async () => await DoSomethingAsync()` constructs? Which one should we prefer and when?

This is not the same question as "should I use `await` in the general case", as here we are dealing with working async code, with lambdas typed as `Func<Task>` which are correctly awaited inside the consuming method. The question concerns how those lambdas are declared, and what the effects of that declaration are.

Comment: Its basically the compiler simplifying the lambda and auto returning the Task from DoSomething... add brackets and now it falls over and you have to either do async or manually return the task.

Comment: Your example async lambda is trivial - it's the equivalent of the `return await` anti-pattern (where that's the only `await` used in the method) - you're involving all of the async machinery for no purpose.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Is there a difference between lambdas declared with and without async

Yes, there's a difference. One is an async lambda and the other is just a task-returning lambda.

An async lambda is compiled into a state machine while the other doesn't so an async lambda has different exception semantics as exceptions are encapsulated in the returned task and can't be thrown synchronously.

It's exactly the same difference that exists in regular methods. For example between this async method:

```
async Task FooAsync()
{
    await DoSomethingAsync("with await");
}
```

And this task-returning method:

```
Task FooAsync()
{
    return DoSomethingAsync("no await");
}
```

Looking at these methods shows the differences more clearly, but as lambdas are just syntactic sugar and are actually compiled into methods that behave just the same as these.

> Which one should we prefer and when?

This really depends on your taste. Using the async keyword generates a state machine which is less performant than simply returning a task. However, the exception semantics may be surprising in some cases.

Take this code for example:

```
Hamster hamster = null;
Func<Task> asyncAction = () => FooAsync(hamster.Name);

var task = asyncAction();
try
{
    await task;
}
catch
{
    // handle
}
```

Would the try-catch block handle the `NullReferenceException` or not?

It will not because the exception is thrown synchronously when calling  `asyncAction`. However the exception **will** be handled in this case as it is captured in the returned task and rethrown when that task is awaited.

```
Func<Task> asyncAction = async () => await FooAsync(hamster.Name);
```

I personally use task-returning lambdas for these one line expression lambdas as they're usually pretty simple. But my team, after a few extremely hurtful bugs, always use the `async` and `await` keywords.

Comment: @Luaan [This TryRoslyn example](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoUlaIoYB0AKgBYBOqAhgCb5k0gDWIO2ADsAEYA2YAMYxBfZiBgBhGAG9sMBTG78hMAG4B7MHRgBZABQBKWfMVmAEjXRFKMclZswAvDAjA+fHGbMAxYBEEAHlJmFgA+GGYEAIBBQWQwDQhnSJBo4SNnCJoAdxowZBgfDQ0YtID9e2s0SmIAOStUQy9vBTUaW2RQlKjY+MSIIxaFAF9TBXGlSjB2tBgUGgThENYikrL0/RRp6FdGw0m5VoVqZGBKZLcPYZgxsfllAWFRcRhLatRKeSOzR9Vt/AwBroVCyGBQVDITDzSHQsa3IA==) definitely shows a difference when using async-await:

Comment: Ok, I think the tl;dr is that: - they are the same in most respects. - But exception handling differs, and if you need correct exception bubbling behaviour you would prefer the lambda with the async...await. - But this version may be less efficient as it generates an additional state machine.

Answer (score 4):

This is the output of IL Viewer for this 2 methods:

```
await Runner(() => DoSomethingAsync("no await"));

    .method private hidebysig instance class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task 
'<RunTheDemo>b__5_0'() cil managed
{
.custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() 
  = (01 00 00 00 )
.maxstack 8

// [42 32 - 42 60]
IL_0000: ldarg.0      // this
IL_0001: ldstr        "no await"
IL_0006: call         instance class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task TestClass::DoSomethingAsync(string)
IL_000b: ret
} // end of method CompanyManagementController::'<RunTheDemo>b__5_0'



await Runner(async () => await DoSomethingAsync("with await"));

.method private hidebysig instance class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task 
'<RunTheDemo>b__5_1'() cil managed
{
.custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncStateMachineAttribute::.ctor(class [mscorlib]System.Type) 
  = (
    01 00 45 57 65 62 43 61 72 64 2e 43 6f 6e 74 72 // ..TestClass
    6f 6c 6c 65 72 73 2e 43 6f 6d 70 61 6e 79 4d 61 // +<<RunTheDemo>
    6e 61 67 65 6d 65 6e 74 43 6f 6e 74 72 6f 6c 6c // b__5_1>d..
    65 72 2b 3c 3c 52 75 6e 54 68 65 44 65 6d 6f 3e  
    62 5f 5f 35 5f 31 3e 64 00 00                    
  )
  // MetadataClassType(TestClass+<<RunTheDemo>b__5_1>d)
.custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute::.ctor() 
  = (01 00 00 00 )
.custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() 
  = (01 00 00 00 )
.maxstack 2
.locals init (
  [0] class TestClass/'<<RunTheDemo>b__5_1>d' V_0,
  [1] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder V_1
)

IL_0000: newobj       instance void TestClass/'<<RunTheDemo>b__5_1>d'::.ctor()
IL_0005: stloc.0      // V_0
IL_0006: ldloc.0      // V_0
IL_0007: ldarg.0      // this
IL_0008: stfld        class TestClass TestClass/'<<RunTheDemo>b__5_1>d'::'<>4__this'
IL_000d: ldloc.0      // V_0
IL_000e: call         valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::Create()
IL_0013: stfld        valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder TestClass/'<<RunTheDemo>b__5_1>d'::'<>t__builder'
IL_0018: ldloc.0      // V_0
IL_0019: ldc.i4.m1    
IL_001a: stfld        int32 TestClass/'<<RunTheDemo>b__5_1>d'::'<>1__state'
IL_001f: ldloc.0      // V_0
IL_0020: ldfld        valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder TestClass/'<<RunTheDemo>b__5_1>d'::'<>t__builder'
IL_0025: stloc.1      // V_1
IL_0026: ldloca.s     V_1
IL_0028: ldloca.s     V_0
IL_002a: call         instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::Start<class TestClass/'<<RunTheDemo>b__5_1>d'>(!!0/*class TestClass/'<<RunTheDemo>b__5_1>d'*/&)
IL_002f: ldloc.0      // V_0
IL_0030: ldflda       valuetype [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder TestClass/'<<RunTheDemo>b__5_1>d'::'<>t__builder'
IL_0035: call         instance class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Tasks.Task [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder::get_Task()
IL_003a: ret
} // end of method CompanyManagementController::'<RunTheDemo>b__5_1'
```

So second one is using async state machine

Comment: I think you'd want to decompile `'<RunTheDemo>b__5_0'` and `'<RunTheDemo>b__5_1'` to see the actual differences.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are the same, but this is a rather simple example. The two are functionally equivalent, you're just (possibly, depending on the compiler) doing more work when using `async`.

A better case to see why `async` lambda's are useful is if you need to deal with a sequence of asynchronous operations - that's what `await` is for, after all:

```
await Runner(async () => await DoSomethingAsync(await httpClient.Get("www.google.com")));
```

Comment: True, the most important thing using await is to using it for purpose. OP silly example is just like synchronus call using asyncs...