# How to get results from List<T>.AsParallel() in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, plinq

I have an asynchronous

```
async static public Task<int> Test(int x, int y)
{
   await Task.Delay(1000);
   return x;
}
```

And I try to run it in parallele on a list. I did like that:

```
var x = new[] { 0, 1 };
var y = new[] { 2, 3 };
var zipped = x.Zip(y, (x, y) => new { x, y }).ToList();
zipped.AsParallel().ForAll(async pair => { await Test(pair.x, pair.y); });
```

But I don't manage to retrieve the list it should return [0,1] cause the AsParallel returns void

Any idea ? also, if there is better solution to speed up in true parralel programming, I take

Comment: You need to consider if your work is IO-limited (the main use case for async),  compute-limited (the main use case for parallel programming), or mixed. And you need an actual problem to begin to consider what solutions would be best. Task parallelism? Data parallelism? SIMD? GPU? For a toy problem like your example there is zero benefit for doing anything in parallel.

Comment: I have added what I am doing now and why I'd like to improve. But to answer, It's mostly IO limited byt the server I guess

Comment: If you are doing anything periodically you should likely be using a *timer*. Using `await Task.WhenAll` as you do may be appropriate, but you need to consider things like rate limiting on the server. And the default windows clock has ~16ms resolution, so you will have a fair amount of quantitation jitter.

Comment: So parralele would be of no help? I can;t find better to assure all calls are being made at exactly the time I want time to be made ?

Comment: Your network card can only send a packet at a time, and in a well optimized application the network card should be the limiting factor.

Comment: One packet at a time is fine: It's like to send one at T-x, one at T-y, ...

Comment: Nicolas your question in its original form has already been answered. What you have [asked later](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78124732/5) about *"calling a server function as close as possible to a certain time"* belongs to a new question. Please post a new question about it.

Answer (score 3):

> `AsParallel` returns `void`

If `AsParallel` would have returned `void` then you would not be able to call `ForAll` on it's result. It is [`ForAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.forall?view=net-8.0) which has `void` return type.

If you want to get the result - use `Select`:

```
List<Task<int>> parallelQuery = zipped.AsParallel()
   .Select(async pair => await Test(pair.x, pair.y))
   // which is almost the same as .Select(pair => Test(pair.x, pair.y))
   .ToList();
```

**BUT** PLINQ is not async/Task-aware (as you can somewhat see by the return type) so if your `Test` is purely [IO-bound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios#recognize-cpu-bound-and-io-bound-work) it does not make much sense here since it will just start all the tasks without actually limiting number of tasks scheduled in parallel (i.e. only task creation is parallelized). Hence it would be similar to just using ordinary LINQ:

```cs
IEnumerable<Task<int>> parallelQuery = zipped
    .Select(async pair => await Test(pair.x, pair.y));
int[] result = await Task.WhenAll(parallelQuery);
```

If you want to limit concurrently "scheduled"/running tasks you can use `SemaphoreSlim` or `Parallel.ForEachAsync`. For example:

```cs
var results = new int[zipped.Count];

Parallel.ForEachAsync(
    zipped.Select((t, i) => (t, i)), // zip with index
    async (tuple, ct) =>
    {
        var t = tuple.t;
        results[tuple.i] = await Test(t.x, t.y); // Pass CancellationToken - ct to test
    });
```

See also:

- [Is there a difference between lambdas declared with and without async](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37133191/2501279)
- [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)
- [Asynchronous programming doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios)
- [Asynchronous Programming in .NET - Introduction, Misconceptions, and Problems](https://wapplegate.com/asynchronous-programming/)

Comment: The first example that features the `zipped.AsParallel()` parallelizes just the creation of the tasks, which is unlikely to be computationally intensive, so parallelizing it shouldn't yield any measurable performance benefits.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I thought I have covered that in my answer =) Added small remark based on your comment.

Comment: I don't think that the answer makes it obvious enough that the `zipped.AsParallel()` example is to be avoided. The example is presented under the rather enticing title *"If you want to get the result - use Select:"*. :-)

Comment: You might as well write `.Select(async pair => await Test(pair.x, pair.y))` as `.Select(pair => Test(pair.x, pair.y))` to help make it clearer.

Comment: I have added a piece so you understand why I am trying to parallelize the code. Maybe it might help directing me if I should call that AsParallel or try using something else